# What Kind of Common Properties Does This Function Exhibit

Tags: functions, logic, relations, equivalence-relations, idempotents

Suppose I have a function. Let's call it $f.$ I can describe some of its behavior in words. What I am wondering about is whether some of this behavior can be summarized by some known types of relations such as Reflexivity, transitivity, idempotency, and so on. In essence, I am trying to learn about the properties of this function.

Here is what I do know.

1. `The function has a variable but FINITE arity; The order of arguments does not matter (commutative?); for my purposes, f(A) is equivalent to A. That is, when there is only one argument, it is the same as if the function has not been applied. When there is more than one argument, the function application "glues" these arguments together into a new entity. This is similar to set-union;`.
2. `f(f(A)) => A`
3. `f(f(A,B)) => f(A,B)`
4. `f(A,f(B)) => f(A,B)`
5. `f(f(A,B,C,...)) => f(A,B,C,...)`

Some of the properties I listed may be redundant. As you can see, this is something resembling an idempotent function and a set-union function. What else can be said about it?

I would also be interested in how one could reduce the properties described above to a smaller set of axiomatic rules/properties from which the above can be reconstructed and built.

Comment: Property  $2$  describes an _involution_...

Comment: Excellent! Any other ideas are welcome :)

Comment: Properties 2 and 3 together? Or each one separately?

Comment: Sorry,  just property  $2$...

Comment: It seems property 3 is just a special case of property 5. So you can remove it?

Comment: @M.Winter Yes. #3 Can be removed.

Comment: Got it. We were on the same page.

Comment: Actually, #2 is also a special case of #5 in the sense of variable arity.

Comment: The only problem is that when there is more than one argument, it does not make sense to talk about them separately. One needs to "tie" them together with that function. Hence, the existence of #5.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Not exactly. If #2 would be a special case, then it would be stating `f(f(A)) => f(A)`.

Comment: I should probably add that for my purposes, `f(A)` is equivalent to `A`. That is, when there is only one argument, it is the same as if the function has not been applied. When there is more than one argument, the function application "glues" these arguments together into a new entity. This is similar to set-union.

Comment: @MadPhysicist This is *definitely* necessary to include into the axioms. Please edit your post, otherwise we are solving a different problem here! If `f(A) => A` is an axiom, then we only also need #1 and #5 and all the other ones follow.

Comment: @MadPhysicist If $f(A)=A$, then *all* of your properties, 2-5, are trivial.

Comment: @DerekElkins in this case, `f(A) ~ A` in that it is about the same when it comes to the resulting meaning. I do not mean that it is equal in some traditional sense of equality.

Comment: @DerekElkins Think of the set-union function. `union A` by itself is the same as `A`. However, `union (A, B)` is a new entity. It is probably possible to think of this as `f(A) = f(empty object, A) = A`

Comment: @MadPhysicist If this equivalence is a congruence, then that doesn't change my argument except to state it with respect to the congruence rather than equality. If it is not a congruence, then I don't think mentioning it is helpful. My comment is based on the fact that most of your properties are of the form $f(X) = X$ (or $f(X)\sim X$? It's not clear what you mean by `=>`.)

Comment: @M.Winter 3 and 5 are of the form $f(X) = X$ or $f(X)\sim X$ with $X = f(A,B)$ in the first case and $f(A,B,C,\dots)$ in the second. 2 and 4 are arguable. If $\sim$ is not a congruence, then there is no reason that $f(f(A))\sim f(A)$ given $f(A)\sim A$ or $f(A,f(B))\sim f(A,B)$ given $f(B)\sim B$, i.e. there is no reason $f$ respects equivalence classes.

Comment: @DerekElkins `=>` means that the thing on the left can be simplified to the thing on the right. When I say "simplified", I mean it in the sense that there are fewer applications of the function `f` in the expression. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: And `~` is not a congruence in the traditional sense. I am just struggling to find a symbol for describing what I mentioned in the example about the set-union.

Comment: I have made an edit to mention that arity is finite.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Presumably you want this notion of "simplification" to be compatible with, at least, the equivalence, i.e. if $X\sim Y$ and $X \leadsto X'$ then $X'\sim Y$. You have an equivalence relation and a simplification relation. How do they relate? (Add these details to the question.)

Comment: @DerekElkins Either you are taking my (somewhat vernacular) terms too mathematically or I am missing what you are asking.

Comment: @MadPhysicist May I ask why are you asking this question? Your current axioms are very general. Are you trying to model something? Or do you have a function and you try to find axioms to describe it?

Comment: @DerekElkins I am trying to do both. I currently have a function that does certain things. I need to deduce rules by which I could simplify expressions involving this function. I would then use these rules to program a solution into a computer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be some set and $X^*$ its [Kleene star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star), i.e. the set or arbitrarliy long finite tuples of elements from $X$. Then $f$ can be considered a function $X^*\to X$. We can reduce the axioms to

1. $f$ is totally commutative, i.e. $f(x_1,...,x_n)=f(x_{\sigma(1)},...,x_{\sigma(n)})\;$ for any permutation $\sigma$.
2. $f(x)=x$.

To see that any of these axioms is completely necessary, lets look for functions which satisfy all of these axioms but one to show that none follows from the others. For this matter we denote by $f_i$ a function which follows all axioms *but* axiom $i$.

- Let $X=A^*$ for some alphabet $A$. Then $f_1$ can be chosen as *concatenation*. For example $$f(a,b,c,d)=abcd\in X.$$ Note that $abcd$ is considered a single element of $X$ and not a quadrupel. Concatenation is not commutative.
- Let $f_2$ be set-union, except that the union of a single set is $\varnothing$.

Set union would be one example function which follow above axioms. Other examples would be addition and multiplication where we can choose $X=\Bbb R$.

Comment: The commutativity constraint can be incorporated by viewing $f$ as a function on (perhaps non-empty) finite multisets.

Comment: How does this capture #4?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Since $\color{red}{f(B)}=\color{blue}B$, we see $f(A,\color{red}{f(B)})=f(A,\color{blue}B)$ just by substitution.